# rotating trailing minus to front of the data in of excel in UNIX

Tags: unix

How to bring the trailing minus sign to beginning of the data in a file in UNIX?

Input

```
ABC 12-
XYZ 10
```

Expected output

```
ABC -12
XYZ 10
```

Comment: what did you try? Is it always on the form `string number`?

Comment: I want to bring trailing minus of decimal to leading minus of a file in unix

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have posted basically the same question three different times

Answer (score 0):

you can try somethink like this;

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
   if (substr($i,length($i),length($i)) == "-") 
        $i = "-"substr($i,1,length($i)-1); 
print }' yourFile
```

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat t1 | column -t
ABC  12-   XYZ  -10   XYZ   22-
XYZ  -10   XYZ  -1-0  XYZ   -1-0  XYZ  -1-0
XYZ  -1-0  10-  ABC   -ABC  ABC-

user@host:/tmp$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (substr($i,length($i),length($i)) == "-") $i = "-"substr($i,1,length($i)-1); print }' t1 | column -t
ABC  -12   XYZ  -10   XYZ   -22
XYZ  -10   XYZ  -1-0  XYZ   -1-0  XYZ  -1-0
XYZ  -1-0  -10  ABC   -ABC  -ABC
```

Comment: I tried but my file input may contain trailing minus at random columns in such a case how to make trailing minus to leading minus.

Comment: Please let me know the UNIX command to fix this kind of problem

Comment: @Abirami : I updated ans. could you try this; what is result;

Comment: Hi Muzido, 

I tried the above script but it still the minus value is at trail end. My input file is the output file of tr command as below.

tr '|' ',' < ST_TEST.csv > Target.csv 

After execution of tr command i executed your script

awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
   if (substr($i,length($i),length($i)) == "-") 
        $i = "-"substr($i,1,length($i)-1); 
print }' Target.csv > Finalout.csv

But still minus is at the end. Many Thanks for your reply and kindly help.